# Removing NAs in dataset

Tags: r, lapply, xlsx, na, venn-diagram

I need to remove NAs from my data but want to keep the position so the length of each column remain same. 
I have used

```
lapply(values, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

and also

```
removeEMPTYstrings <- function(x) { newVectorWOstrings <- x[x != ""] return(newVectorWOstrings)}

lists <- lapply(as.list(counts), removeEMPTYstrings)
```

but both of them are unable to remove the NAs. Sometimes I'm able to remove them, but lose the positioning and the column length gets changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsWp.png)

Comment: i used this code to import data 'Lists <- read_xlsx("venntable.xlsx")'.

Answer (score 1):

How about below?

```
x[is.na(x)] <- ""
```

Comment: > venn.plot <- venn.diagram(VENN.LIST , NULL, fill=c("aquamarine", "lightgreen","cyan2", "darkolivegreen1"), alpha=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), cex = 2, cat.fontface=2, category.names=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c("", "1")) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 329

Comment: i am trying to apply this protocol on my data https://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-venn-diagrams/

Answer (score 0):

Removing NAs while keeping the same column length is not possible as I know. You passically have to options:

1. You can replace the NAs by something else as @MSW Data showed.
2. You can store all rows with NAs in a vector and then remove all NAs. The original length is the new length of the position vector and the length of the `data.frame` without NAs.

The the second option you can do in the following way:

```
na_pos = which(apply(data, 1, function(x)sum(is.na(x))>0))
data = na.omit(data)
total_length = length(na_pos) + nrow(data)
```

Comment: second option removed all the data. i think its removing the complete row which has NA in any column

Comment: Yes, that is the case. You cannot remove single cells, just rows or columns. Normally one removes rows because a row indicates a case. The only other option is to replace the NAs by other values depending what you want.